# SFML undefined reference to `std::basic_streambuf...'

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, linker-errors, sfml

I'm trying to compile the SFML example program:

```
#define SFML_STATIC 

#include <iostream>
#include <SFML-2.5.1\\include\\SFML\\Window.hpp>

using namespace std;

namespace SF = sf;

int main()
{
    SF::Window window {SF::VideoMode{600, 600}, "Test1"};

    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        SF::Event event;

        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == SF::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

First, I compile with

```
g++ -c main.cpp -IH:\CPPLIBS\SFML-2.5.1\include -DSFML_STATIC
```

And then I link with

```
g++ main.o -o main -LH:\CPPLIBS\SFML-2.5.1\lib -lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32
```

But at the linking phase, I get the error

```
H:\CPPLIBS\SFML-2.5.1\lib/libsfml-system-s.a(Err.cpp.obj):Err.cpp:(.rdata+0x80):
undefined reference to `std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char>>::seekpos(std::fpos<int>, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
```

I searched online for solutions pretty much everywhere and tried to fix it myself changing the libraries order, compiling and linking with a single command and changing parameters, but I really can't fix it and nobody seems to have had this exact problem.
For compiling I'm using, as you can see, the g++ compiler shipped with WinLibs Mingw.

Comment: Your compiler doesn't seem to match SFML. Have you read the red https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-cb.php#installing-sfml and https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/?

Comment: I didn't read the second one because as you see I'm not using CodeBlocks, about the first one: I red it but found people on stackoverflow saying that "indicated compiler version and compiler version have to match" wasn't really mandatory, that they were perfectly fine with compiling SFML on much more modern versions and that the indicated version was way too and unnecessarily old.

Comment: So, you got build issues, and you still have own opinion based on SO posts and contrary to the official manual. Both links are about mingw, idk why you see only codeblocks there.

Comment: If it's working for them, I don't see why it shouldn't work for others, and using such an old version doesn't seem the best thing to do, so, if it's there, I'd like to know a way to use it with modern compiler versions.

Comment: idk if this will help but I've had such a nightmare with this too whenever I wanted to use fonts, way to many gaps in my knowledge I guess. Apparently you need the msvcrt version of winlibs not the ucrt one if that's the one you have this may help. Once I had the msvcrt version setup I was still having problems building my projects, so I literally started fresh with sfml, built it again with my compilers setup how they are now, still problems, so I start again, this time also using a fresh SFML I just unzipped... It seems to be working now! Even when using fonts!

Answer (score 0):

The default C++ dialect in GCC 12 is `-std=gnu++17`. Try the commands

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -c main.cpp -IH:\CPPLIBS\SFML-2.5.1\include -DSFML_STATIC

g++ -std=gnu++11 main.o -o main -LH:\CPPLIBS\SFML-2.5.1\lib -lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32
```

If it does not help, see my comment to the question. You may need to build SFML from sources.

> If you feel like your version of GCC can't work with the precompiled SFML libraries, don't hesitate to [build SFML yourself](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/compile-with-cmake.php), it's not complicated.

Comment: If I build it from source I'll be able to use it with any compiler version I want? BTW: I'm getting the same error with your commands

Comment: *I'll be able to use it with any compiler version I want* No, you will not be able to use it with any compiler. You will be able to build with the compiler version you use for SFML build.

Comment: That's what I meant, thanks, I'll try. Do I have to accept your answer now or do I have to wait for a successful compilation after I compile SFML?

Comment: It is up to you. The answer has not solved the issue how you wanted.

Comment: I tried to build the library following the official tutorial, but after a serie of "Building CXX object..." I got two "undefined reference to _setjmp".

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when using Clang + SFML for Windows. The solution is just rebuild the static SFML libs with:

```
Cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DSFML_USE_STATIC_STD_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -B build -G "Ninja"

ninja -C build
```